# Pandas how to read 0-padded number with read_fwf?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I'm using read_fwf to do the obvious, but pandas will remove left-padded zeroes from the numeric string codes we work with and tread the type as int. Same goes for various codes we have to use which are in "xxxx.yyy" format, it'll convert to float and chop off leading zeroes.

This isn't a problem for columns where the codes are all the same length, but many of them vary in length (ie: `001234` and `0001234`) so we can't reliably zfill the data -- once pandas parses the zeroes off they're lost.

I know dtype for read_fwf is coming next major update, but I'm really hoping there's a way right now to prevent pandas from ruining my data. Anybody know?

Sample file (test.fwf):

```
0001234  000.1234
001234   123.4567
00001234 345.6789
0005678  678.1234
0005678  000.1200
0005678  012.2301
0005678  234.5678
```

testfwf.py:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('test.fwf', colspecs=[(0, 8),(9, 19)])
df.columns = ['code_a', 'code_b']
```

---

```
In[2]: from testfwf import df
In[3]: df
Out[3]: 
   code_a    code_b
0    1234  123.4567
1    1234  345.6789
2    5678  678.1234
3    5678    0.1200
4    5678   12.2301
5    5678  234.5678
```

Comment: Can your provide a sample file that reproduces the problem, and a minimal set of code that shows the problem?

Comment: Specify the dtype with the dtype option?
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf.html

Comment: @TheBlackCat Added example.

Comment: @LiamFoley `(Unsupported with engine=’python’)`

Comment: @LiamFoley btw, not sure why, but `read_fwf` doesn't seem to support `dtype` even though it's in the document http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472566/python-read-fwf-error-dtype-is-not-supported-with-python-fwf-parser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you're losing a row of data. Set `header=None` to specify there's no header. Second, you can use converters to specify a column should be a string and prevent stripping leading 0's:

```
In [96]: pd.read_fwf('test.fwf', header=None, converters={0:str, 1:str})
Out[96]: 
          0         1
0   0001234  000.1234
1    001234  123.4567
2  00001234  345.6789
3   0005678  678.1234
4   0005678  000.1200
5   0005678  012.2301
6   0005678  234.5678
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using `np.genfromtxt` (which will accept `dtype=str` and column widths in `delimiter`), but I prefer your approach because then you'll get automatic interpretation for the *other* columns.

Comment: @DSM Yeah `np.genfromtxt` would probably work better if there were a lot of columns and you wanted to read them all as text.